# Can i use php inside a form element like this?

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

I'm doing a campaign project in which the admin can reserve some seats using admin panel. When he wants to edit it,previously selected seats should highlight. This is what i've done for achieving this

```
if ($mode == 'EDIT')
        {
            $k=1;
            for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
            {
            for($j=1;$j<=10;$j++)
            { ?>
                <div id='<?php echo $k ;?>' class="seat_selection"
                <?php foreach($seat_data as $seats)
                {
                if($seats->iSeatNumber == $k)
                {?>
                    style='min-height:25px;min-width:25px;background-color:#12B22F;float:left;margin:0 0 5px 10px;cursor:pointer;'
                <?php
                }
                else
                {?>
                    style='min-height:25px;min-width:25px;background-color:#969696;float:left;margin:0 0 5px 10px;cursor:pointer;'
                <?php
                }
                }
                ?>
                >
                <?php echo $k;?>
                </div>
            <?php $k++;
            } ?>
            <br /><br />
            <?php
            }
        }
```

But only the first seat among the selected seats is being highlighted(like **5th seat** as shown in screenshot). Rest remains unchanged.

**Screenshot**
[image: Seats Selection]

I think the problem is with the looping of `foreach`. Am i doing it in the wrong way? Or is there any other method? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using `datamapper`(db operations) for `codeigniter`(php framework).

Comment: what does `$seats->isSeatNumber()` return?

Comment: can you give an example of the `$seat_data` ?

Comment: Show the data in the database. Show the way you take that data. Help us to help you.

Comment: @deifwud `$seat_data` returns array of the table data like 'campaignId','seatNumber' etc..`$seats->iSeatNumber()` returns the previously reserved seats.. **5,10,15** in this case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your task, I see this as a really bad way to achieve it.

Try making an array with all the highlighted seats first:

```
$highlighted = array();
foreach($seat_data as $seat) {
    $highlighted[] = $seat->iSeatNumber;
}

$k = 1;
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
{
    for($j=1;$j<=10;$j++)
    {
        if(in_array($k, $highlighted))
        {
             echo '<div id="'.$k.'" class="seat_selection" style="min-height:25px;min-width:25px;background-color:#12B22F;float:left;margin:0 0 5px 10px;cursor:pointer;">'.$k.'</div>';
        } else {
             echo '<div id="'.$k.'" class="seat_selection" style="min-height:25px;min-width:25px;background-color:#969696;float:left;margin:0 0 5px 10px;cursor:pointer;">'.$k.'</div>';
        }
        $k++;
    }
    echo "<br/><br/>";
}
```

It's much cleaner. Though I didn't test this it should work.

Comment: Thanks mate.. working great :) Thanks for the hint. I was equating a single value to an array :O. `in_array()` is the right way of doing it

Answer (score 2):

This is an example similar to Vlakarados' but only uses one loop. The idea is that you build an array of the highlighted seat IDs, then check if `$i` is in this array when looping, and if so, add the highlighted class.

Instead of having all that inline CSS you could create a class for highlighted/not highlighted, like in the example below.

```
$highlightedSeats = array(2, 6, 12, 21, 44);
for($i=1; $i<=100; $i++) { 
    $class = (in_array($i, $highlightedSeats)) ? 'highlighted' : 'not-highlighted';
    echo '<div id="' . $i . '" class="seat_selection ' . $class . '">' . $i . '</div>';
    if($i % 10 == 0) {
        echo '<br /><br />';
    } 
}
```

Comment: Yes, even a better solution for this task, but I think using mod to put line breaks is a bit less multipurpose, anyway, I would use your way myself.

Answer (score 0):

Try change to:

```
if ($mode == 'EDIT'){
$k=1;
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){
for($j=1;$j<=10;$j++){ ?>
<?php foreach($seat_data as $seats){
if($seats->iSeatNumber == $k){
$style="min-height:25px;min-width:25px;background-color:#12B22F;float:left;margin:0 0 5px 10px;cursor:pointer;";
}
else{
$style='min-height:25px;min-width:25px;background-color:#969696;float:left;margin:0 0 5px 10px;cursor:pointer;';
} 
}
?>
<div id='<?php echo $k ;?>' class="seat_selection" style="<?php echo $style; ?>">
<?php echo $k;?>
</div>
<?php $k++;
} ?>
<br /><br />
<?php
}
}
```